# How do I create a filter with AngularJS to show/hide certain items?

Tags: html, angularjs, django

I am trying to create a filter to show and hide certain items in my list. I already have two filters set but I can't seem to get this one working. As you can see I had some help with the others but this help is no longer with me. I am running AngularJS.

So far, I have the following:

1) To show and hide prices.

```
<h4 class="pl_header">Hidden Prices</h4>
            <ul class="price_list_filter">
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <span>Show</span>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="faChkSqr pull-right" ng-model="filter_hi" value="Hi" ng-change="hidden_show()">

                    </label>
                </li>
```

2)Added it into my body.

`<tbody ng-repeat="price_level in price_levels | orderBy:propertyName:reverse | filter:filterByCategory | filter:filterByType | filter:searchSKU | filter:filterByHide"
                ng-style="{ 'background-color' : (price_level.buyer) ? 'lightgray' : 'white' }">`

3) My javascript.

```
$scope.hidden_show = function() {
        $scope.UIfilterby.hide = [];
        if($scope.filter_hi == false){
            $scope.UIfilterby.hide.push("Hi");
        }
        $scope.UIfilterby.hide = $scope.UIfilterby.hide.join();

    }
```

and

```
$scope.filterByHide = function(price_level){
        if($scope.UIfilterby.hide){
            return ($scope.UIfilterby.hide.indexOf(price_level.hidden) !== false);
        }else{
            return {};
        }
    }
```

I followed similar structures to the other two filters, one was filter by category and the other as by type. Maybe I need to add it to my filters.py in django? I am new to this, any help would be appreciated. Thank you.